# Combine arrays and make unique vars

Tags: php

I have some arrays that I would like to combine to one and only take the same once, here's my arrays:

```
["ar1"]
["ar2"]
["ar2"]
["ar3"]
["ar4","ar2","ar5"]
["ar6","ar1"]
["ar5","ar3","ar7"]
["ar8","ar9","ar7"]
["ar3"]
```

I want it to return:

ar1,ar2,ar3,ar4,ar5,ar6,ar7,ar8,ar9

Is there an easy way to do that in PHP?

Comment: [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) are your friends.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can do it:

```
$input = [
  ["ar1"],
  ["ar2"],
  ["ar2"],
  ["ar3"],
  ["ar4","ar2","ar5"],
  ["ar6","ar1"],
  ["ar5","ar3","ar7"],
  ["ar8","ar9","ar7"],
  ["ar3"],
];

if ($input) {
  $merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $input);
  $unique = array_unique($merged);
  $final = array_values($unique);
} else {
  $final = [];
}

print_r($final);
```

Output would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ar1
    [1] => ar2
    [2] => ar3
    [3] => ar4
    [4] => ar5
    [5] => ar6
    [6] => ar7
    [7] => ar8
    [8] => ar9
)
```

Some notes re code:

`$merged` -- this basically merges all items in input arrays into single array. We need `if` to take care of trivial case when there are zero input arrays (`array_merge` will fail in this case).

`$unique` -- here we remove all duplicates.

`$final` -- but `array_unique` also messes with array keys (instead of 0, 1, 2 you can get anything like 5, 7, 12, i.e. non-consecutive indexes), so, we should tidy up keys. This is optional step, depending on your task you might skip it. Here is how output looks if you skip this step (look at keys):

```
Array
(
    [0] => ar1
    [1] => ar2
    [3] => ar3
    [4] => ar4
    [6] => ar5
    [7] => ar6
    [11] => ar7
    [12] => ar8
    [13] => ar9
)
```